# Cannot pass data from _data to template in 11ty (Eleventy)

Tags: node.js

I have read the doc and tried to pass data from _data to my templates, but it just doesn't work. What have I done wrong?

My .eleventyjs:

```
const eleventyNavigationPlugin = require("@11ty/eleventy-navigation");

module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {
  eleventyConfig.addPlugin(eleventyNavigationPlugin);
  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('css');
  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('js');
  return {
    dir: {
      "input": "views_njk",
      "includes": "includes",
    },
    "htmlTemplateEngine": "njk",
    "markdownTemplateEngine": "njk",
    "dataTemplateEngine": "njk",
    "passthroughFileCopy": true,
  }
};
```

My data(_data/metadata.json):

```
{
  "title": "Your Blog Name",
  "url": "https://myurl.com/",
  "description": "I am writing about my experiences as a naval navel-gazer.",
  "feed": {
    "subtitle": "I am writing about my experiences as a naval navel-gazer.",
    "filename": "feed.xml",
    "path": "/feed/feed.xml",
    "id": "https://myurl.com/"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "Your Name Here",
    "email": "youremailaddress@example.com"
  }
}
```

My template:

```
<html lang="zh-HK" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <head>
      <title>{{ metadata.title }}</title>
  </head>
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Just ran into this issue myself on a fork of the base blog repo. Did you figure out the issue?