# How to access json data file information from include file in 11ty / eleventy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, eleventy

I need help with [Eleventy (11ty)](https://www.11ty.dev/), the static website generator.

In the [default `_data/` directory](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/config/#directory-for-global-data-files) I have the following `navigation.json` file:

```json
[
  {
    "name":"Home",
    "url":"/"
  },
  {
    "name":"Foo",
    "url":"/foo/"
  }
]
```

I can access the information in `navigation.json` from the `default.html` template in `_includes/layouts/` with:

```
<ul>
{% for page in navigation %}
  <li><a href="{{ page.url }}" title="{{ page.title }}">{{ page.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However, with the same liquid for loop I can not access the information in `navigation.json` from a `navigation.html` include in `_includes/` which I render in `default.html` with `{%- render 'navigation.html' -%}`.

I am only getting the empty `ul`'s.

My `.eleventy.js` file:

```js
const pluginTOC = require("eleventy-plugin-toc"); // Importing the eleventy-plugin-toc module
const eleventySass = require("eleventy-sass"); // Importing the eleventy-sass module
const htmlmin = require("html-minifier"); // Importing the html-minifier module
const markdownIt = require("markdown-it"); // Importing the markdown-it module
const markdownItAnchor = require("markdown-it-anchor"); // Importing the markdown-it-anchor module
const markdownItAttrs = require("markdown-it-attrs"); // Importing the markdown-it-attrs module
const markdownItFootnote = require("markdown-it-footnote"); // Importing the markdown-it-footnote module
const slugify = import("@sindresorhus/slugify"); // Importing the @sindresorhus/slugify module

module.exports = (eleventyConfig) => { // Exporting a function that takes eleventyConfig as a parameter
  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("_src/assets/css"); // Configuring Eleventy to copy the _src/assets/css directory to the output
  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("_src/assets/examples"); // Configuring Eleventy to copy the _src/assets/examples directory to the output
  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("_src/assets/fonts"); // Configuring Eleventy to copy the _src/assets/fonts directory to the output
  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("_src/assets/graphics"); // Configuring Eleventy to copy the _src/assets/graphics directory to the output
  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("_src/assets/scripts"); // Configuring Eleventy to copy the _src/assets/scripts directory to the output

  eleventyConfig.addPlugin(eleventySass); // Adding the eleventySass plugin to Eleventy's configuration
  eleventyConfig.addPlugin(pluginTOC); // Adding the pluginTOC plugin to Eleventy's configuration
  eleventyConfig.addPlugin(markdownIt); // Adding the markdownIt plugin to Eleventy's configuration

  const markdownItOptions = { // Setting options for the markdown-it plugin
    breaks: true, // Enable automatic line breaks
    html: true, // Enable HTML tags in the markdown
    linkify: true, // Convert URLs into clickable links
    typographer: true // Enable smart typography
  };

  const markdownLib = markdownIt(markdownItOptions) // Creating a new instance of the markdown-it plugin with the specified options
    .use(markdownItAttrs) // Applying the markdown-it-attrs plugin
    .use(markdownItFootnote) // Applying the markdown-it-footnote plugin
    .use(markdownItAnchor, { // Applying the markdown-it-anchor plugin with custom options
      permalink: markdownItAnchor.permalink.ariaHidden({ // Configuring the permalink style
        class: "anchor anchor__anchor", // CSS class for the permalink anchor
        symbol: "#", // Symbol to be displayed for the permalink
        placement: 'after', // Placement of the permalink relative to the heading text
        slugify: (s) => slugify(s) // Custom slugify function for generating permalinks
      })
    });

  eleventyConfig.setLibrary("md", markdownLib); // Setting the markdown library to be used by Eleventy

  eleventyConfig.addTransform("htmlmin", function(content, outputPath) { // Adding a transform to minify HTML output
    if (this.outputPath && this.outputPath.endsWith(".html")) { // Checking if the output path ends with ".html"
      let minified = htmlmin.minify(content, { // Minifying the HTML content using html-minifier
        useShortDoctype: true, // Use short doctype (e.g., <!DOCTYPE html>)
        removeComments: true, // Remove HTML comments
        collapseWhitespace: true // Collapse whitespace
      });
      return minified; // Returning the minified HTML content
    }
    return content; // Returning the original content if it's not an HTML file
  });

  return {
    dir: {
      data: "_data", // Configuring the data directory
      includes: "_includes", // Configuring the includes directory
      input: "_src", // Configuring the input directory
      output: "_site" // Configuring the output directory
    }
  };
};
```

What do I have to do, to access the information? I am using all the default directories and accessing works in the `default.html` template. Confused. Thank you for your help in advance.

This may be related to:
[Cannot pass data from _data to template in 11ty (Eleventy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62119773/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think {%- render "" -%} is valid as per [the supported features mentioned in 11ty docs](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/liquid/#supported-features). You should change:

```
{%- render 'navigation.html' -%}
```

to:

```
{%- include 'navigation.html' -%}
```